# A python web framework that works well with Sybase?

Tags: python, template-engine, sybase-asa

I have found lots that work well with any other datastore, but none that work well with Sybase. Please advise !! Thanks, Richard.

[ Edit: http://code.google.com/p/sqlany-django/ isn't sufficient - I need Sybase support,not SQL Anywhere ]

Comment: What does the template engine have to do with the database?

Comment: The data I need is stored in Sybase and I would like to not re-invent the wheel by writing my own django webpy web.py etc etc. There is no option to use another datastore

Comment: Neither Django nor web.py is a template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that what you are actually asking for is Web Framework that has database abstraction layer supporting Sybase. Am I right? For starters you could have a look at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/07/dialects/sybase.html), which is an ORM used by some of the web frameworks and can be used with others (web.py, CherryPy, etc.).

Comment: I think the combination of cherrypy + sqlalchemy might be the way forward... Thanks for the intros / reminders etc.